# Extract (for OCR) hard-coded video subtitles

Tags: python, video, ocr, subtitle, video-subtitles

Many Korean videos on YouTube have hard-coded subtitles (e.g. https://youtu.be/Zyd6hAvxTnc).

The desired end result would be the OCR'd subtitles in text format.

I have a semi-manual process of downloading the video with yt-dlp, using ffmpeg to create images (e.g. every 1s), bulk crop by fixed dimensions using ImageMagick (hoping the subtitles don't go multi-line...), OCRing using Tesseract (with mixed results - PowerToy's Text Extractor seems much better, but it's very manual), then removing duplicates.

It's not a great solution.

I've tried using OpenCV but without success.

Does anyone know of either:

a) a tool that does this automatically

b) a better way to automate this process (ideally into a single Python script, ideally with automatic detection of the subtitles rather than fixed cropping).

Thanks!

Comment: Looking online, I found this [Master's Thesis](https://liu.diva-portal.org/smash/get/diva2:1331490/FULLTEXT01.pdf) by Jonathan Sjölund, which describes a related problem, detecting frozen captions. As part of detecting frozen captions, the author needed to detect captions, and he describes ten techniques for detecting captions in section 2.2.2.

Comment: @NickODell So this is Master's-level material? Wow. Having a read, I think it's a bit above my head haha. Thanks though!

Answer (score 1):

A possible workflow might be:

1. Use `ffmpeg` to convert the MP4 video to static images, e.g. `ffmpeg -i myvideo.mp4 -start_number 1 -vf fps=1 frame-%04d.png`
2. Extract text with [python's opencv](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=opencv%20text) or some library that wraps it eg [`easyocr`](https://github.com/JaidedAI/EasyOCR). On silicon macs you might want to take advantage of apple's hardware accelerated AI chips for livetext detection via hooks such as [macOCR](https://github.com/xulihang/macOCR.git).
3. Stitch together the extracted text into something like SRT (might be tricky to get the on-off timings right, the [`srt`](https://github.com/cdown/srt) module might help with this).

There is [subtitles_extract](https://github.com/krviolent/subtitles_extract) which attempts to put it all together (a mixture of bash and python) but it's apparently a one-off feat and needs extra tweaking in order to work, yet it gives a rough idea of how this can be done.

<sup>Note: you might also want to crop the video with ffmpeg first in order to only work with the area that contains subtitles and avoid recognizing other text in the video such street signs, credits etc.</sup>

Comment: I had tried something similar before but didn't have luck. However, I put some more effort into it today and it worked! The files are here: https://github.com/jamesdeluk/YouTube-Korean-OCR

Comment: awesome! thanks for sharing! I've also put together all the files for Chinese subs extraction along with trad-simp-pinyin generation and deepl translation; the OCR part is using the apple hardware AI chips (arm64 m1/m2-only) so not portable to other platforms, but works very fast with multithreading: https://github.com/glowinthedark/subtitles-ocr